# Why bootstrap uib dropdown won't work with the select element

Tags: html, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I run my angularJS (ver 1.4.9) app without the uib-.. directives, the select works but displays the items already open and the button does nothing.

It won't integrate with the dropdown menu component. All the examples I've seen use the unordered list and list item structure and the bootstrap UI dropdown appears based around the ui and li elements leading to the obvious question - why those elements and not select, option elements.

I would like to keep this: `ng-options="e for e in vm.plannedEmployees track by e"`
as I know it works and took a week of hacking to find it (though I don't understand it's complexity)

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <select ng-options="e for e in vm.plannedEmployees track by e" 
            multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedEmployee" 
            ng-change="vm.employeeSelectClick(selectedEmployee)">
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> All the examples I've seen use the unordered list and list item structure and the bootstrap UI dropdown appears based around the ui and li elements leading to the obvious question - why those elements and not select, option elements.

The uib-bootstrap project is aimed to port the bootstrap plugins into Angular directives, the bootstrap style defines the Dropdown by using a `<ul>` and `<li>` elements and uses CSS that select/target these elements, the uib directives just replace the jQuery code you would use in a non Angular page.

Also, in a UI sense, a select is not the same as a dropdown, in Angular sense, a select is an input that would normally expose an ngModel, uib-dropdown doesn't expose an ngModel (and subsequently, won't allow you to use directives that require it, such an ngChange or ngModelOptions).

That being said, you may want to look at [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if that info was explained clearly in the docs

Comment: it says on site, right under dependencies: `This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS`, it is implied that the directives are made to work under the styles and markup hierarchy defined by bootstrap. also, I personally don't use the dropdown, I think it's aweful, uiSelect is a lot nicer :)